# How to prevent users from booting at safe mode

Tags: windows, boot

I need to prevent users from booting at safe mode because they are using it to cheat on Kaspersky endpoint security.

Comment: You could install another bootloader, such as Grub.

Comment: With which version of Windows? And don't forget to prevent booting from an alternate disk or bootloader, and put a password on BIOS settings.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1:**

Using the registry editor, you can rename the following keys:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SafeBoot contains:

1. Minimal
2. Network

Change these names (i.e. do not remove them), call them _Minimal and _Network (as an example), reboot the machine and try to run in to Save Mode. When trying the machine either reboots or gives a BSOD (Windows XP)

**Method 2:**

1. From the CLI type the following with administrative privileges, this will make ntldr writeable:

attrib -r -s -h -a c:\ntldr

2. Create a backup of c:\ntldr and keep this copy on an external media.
3. Edit the ntlr file using a hex editor.
4. Scroll down to the offset line “00000770”, then change the values “0F 85 09″ to “90 90 90″.
5. Again, from the CLI type the following with administrative privileges, this will make ntldr read only again:

attrib +r +s +h +a c:\ntldr

6. Reboot your machine, booting in safe mode should no longer work.

!!! Please note that this is the procedure for Windows XP machines, I have NOT tested this with Win7 and up.